# Scope overlap and cross-posting

Tags: discussion, scope

Re: [When does travel become residency?](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/when-does-travel-become-residency) —

We talked about minimizing the overlap between traveling and expatriating, but the differing opinions on how to do so seemed to widen it (by the fact that they’re so different).

At least one person offered some of the reasons cross posting is undesirable.

**Is it acceptable to post the question on one site, and on the other put only the title (make sure it’s the actual question) with a body like “This question is a duplicate of (URI).  Please answer there.”**

Then ask a moderator to lock it.

My rationale is that people in group A may be interested in a borderline question but not be following group B.  (Might have a side-effect of getting more people in group B!)

Comment: I might add that I think I am in the very center of the overlap by several of the definitions.

Comment: I think this is just a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu.

Comment: I guess we have different definitions of “duplicate”.  That suggests multi-posting; I’m speculating on a way to avoid it.  That claims one site is **always** better than any other for a question; the topic I cited strongly suggests “not always.”

Answer (score 5):

No, such "questions" will be not acceptable, because they are actually not questions, but only references to questions. Technically, the would be link-only questions.

However, there are discussions about strenghtening the relations between sites on Meta.SE, which you can support:

- [Display other SE site links in the linked questions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/display-other-se-site-links-in-the-linked-questions-sidebar)
- [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet?lq=1)